# Best way to make multiple asyn calls from a REST Service to external soap webservices

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, web-services, asynchronous

I have a WCF Service which inturn call 4 soap webservices (total response time for 4 services are more than a minute) for a single transaction and finally it will log the transaction status in the SQL 2008 database. I have first used Background worker and it  was working fine till 30 calls , if we increase the volume more than 30 calls then Backgroundworker process is getting cancelled . Now i am thinking of using Multi threads. Can some one advice which is the best asnyc method for my situation.

Comment: Without a code example, it's impossible to answer.  You are using multiple threads when you use `BackgroundWorker`, and there is no reason you would be limited to 30 instances of it.  I would first make sure you don't have a bug before you go changing your design.

Comment: I don't have any bug but when the calls increase above 30 , it makes problem. Some times it processing only 36 calls out of 60 calls and sometime it is processing 47 calls out of same 60 calls.

Answer (score 1):

When you have that many concurrent operations it makes sense to switch to async IO. There are multiple models available. The best one is clearly async-await in combination with the TPL. I encourage you to look up on it.

The reason why `BackgroundWorker` gave you trouble is because synchronous IO uses threads and often you hit some non-deterministic limit with that.

In any case, abandon thread-based solutions because they have trouble at high degree of parallelism.